# response code 500 when returning an object using @ResponseBody

Tags: java, spring, jakarta-ee, spring-mvc

I'm fairly new to spring Restful programming The requirement to use the controller method as a rest service, so I'm trying to return an object in a JSON format, but for some reason I'm getting  a response code as 500 with no errors and exceptions in log files.

But it is successfully working if I the return type is of a string rather an object

I'm using the jackson dependencies and I'm configuring in context file and  in a assumption that converts the object to json format and puts in the response body on using @ResponseBody annotation

//Response code 500 If I return an object

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/donorSummary", method = RequestMethod.GET,produces = "application/json")
  @PreAuthorize("hasRole('"+PermissionConstants.VIEW_DONOR+"')")
  public @ResponseBody Donor donorSummaryGenerator(HttpServletRequest request, Model model,HttpServletResponse response,
      @RequestParam(value = "donorId", required = false) Long donorId) {

       //some code here

        return donorObject; 

     }
```

//Working if I return a string

```
 @RequestMapping(value = "/donorSummary", method = RequestMethod.GET,produces = "application/json")
      @PreAuthorize("hasRole('"+PermissionConstants.VIEW_DONOR+"')")
      public @ResponseBody StringdonorSummaryGenerator(HttpServletRequest request, Model model,HttpServletResponse response,
          @RequestParam(value = "donorId", required = false) Long donorId) {

            //some oode here 

            return donorObject.toString(); 

         }
```

ApplicationContext File

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
  xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
  xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
  xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
  xmlns:task="http://www.springframework.org/schema/task"
  xmlns:int="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration"
  xmlns:int-mail="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/mail"
  xmlns:security="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
  xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.1.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.1.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/spring-integration-2.2.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/mail
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/mail/spring-integration-mail-2.2.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/util
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util-2.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-2.5.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/task http://www.springframework.org/schema/task/spring-task-3.1.xsd">

  <!-- Annotations like PreAuthorize, needed here and not in security-v2v-servlet.xml
       as this is the MVC configuration dealing with URLs??? -->
  <security:global-method-security pre-post-annotations="enabled" />
  <context:property-placeholder location="classpath:database.properties" />

  <!-- Configures the @Controller programming model -->
  <mvc:annotation-driven />

  <context:component-scan base-package="controller" />
  <context:component-scan base-package="repository" />
  <context:component-scan base-package="model" />
  <context:component-scan base-package="viewmodel" />
  <context:component-scan base-package="tasks" />
  <context:component-scan base-package="utils" />
  <context:component-scan base-package="security" />

  <bean id="messageSource"
    class="org.springframework.context.support.ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource">
    <property name="basenames">
      <list>
        <value>classpath:messages</value>
      </list>
    </property>
  </bean>

  <bean id="viewResolver"
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.UrlBasedViewResolver">
    <property name="viewClass"
      value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView" />
    <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/" />
    <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
  </bean>

  <bean id="dataSource" class="com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource"
          destroy-method="close">
        <property name="driverClass" value="${database.driver}" />
        <property name="jdbcUrl" value="${database.url}" />
        <property name="user" value="${database.user}" />
        <property name="password" value="${database.password}" /> 

        <!-- these are C3P0 properties -->
        <property name="acquireIncrement" value="${database.acquireIncrement}" />
        <property name="minPoolSize" value="${database.minPoolSize}" />
        <property name="maxPoolSize" value="${database.maxPoolSize}" />
        <property name="maxIdleTime" value="${database.maxIdleTime}" />
  </bean>

  <!-- persistence unit name comes from persistence.xml -->
  <bean id="entityManagerFactory"
    class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean"
    p:dataSource-ref="dataSource" p:persistenceUnitName="v2v">
    <property name="jpaProperties">
      <props>
        <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect</prop>
        <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
        <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">none</prop>
        <prop key="javax.persistence.validation.mode">none</prop>
      </props>
    </property>
  </bean>

  <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
    <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory" />
  </bean>

  <bean id="applicationContextProvider" class="repository.events.ApplicationContextProvider"></bean>
  <bean id="multipartResolver" class="org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver">
  </bean>

  <mvc:interceptors>
    <bean id="loggingInterceptor" class="interceptor.LoggingInterceptor" />
  </mvc:interceptors>

  <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />

  <task:executor id="executor" pool-size="5"/>
  <task:scheduler id="scheduler" pool-size="5"/>
  <task:annotation-driven scheduler="scheduler" executor="executor"/>

    <property name="javaMailProperties">
      <props>
        <prop key="mail.smtp.starttls.enable">true</prop>
          <prop key="mail.smtp.auth">true</prop>
       </props>
    </property>
  </bean>

  <int:service-activator input-channel="receiveEmailChannel"
                         ref="emailReceiverService"
                         method="receive" />

  <int-mail:inbound-channel-adapter id="imapAdapter"
    store-uri="imaps://${imap.username}:${imap.password}@imap.googlemail.com:993/INBOX"
    java-mail-properties="javaMailProperties"
    channel="receiveEmailChannel"
    should-delete-messages="false"
    should-mark-messages-as-read="false"
    auto-startup="true"
    >



</beans>
```

pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>bsis</groupId>
    <name>BSIS</name>
    <description>(BSIS)</description>
    <artifactId>bsis</artifactId>
    <version>0.1</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <properties>
        <webapp.name>bsis</webapp.name>
        <cxf-version>2.2.10</cxf-version>
        <liquibase.propertyFile>liquibase/liquibase.properties</liquibase.propertyFile>
    </properties>

    <build>
        <finalName>${webapp.name}</finalName>
        <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
        <testSourceDirectory>test</testSourceDirectory>

        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>src</directory>
                <excludes>
                    <exclude>**/*.java</exclude>
                </excludes>

            </resource>

        </resources>

        <testResources>
            <testResource>
                <directory>test</directory>
                <filtering>false</filtering>
                <includes>
                    <include>**/*.xml</include>
                    <include>**/*.sql</include>
                </includes>
            </testResource>
        </testResources>

        <plugins>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.12</version>
                <configuration>
                    <useFile>true</useFile>
                    <includes>
                        <include>**/*Tests.java</include>
                        <include>**/*Test.java</include>

                    </includes>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>**/Abstract*.java</exclude>
                    </excludes>
                    <reuseForks>false</reuseForks>
                    <forkCount>1</forkCount>
                    <junitArtifactName>junit:junit</junitArtifactName>
                    <parallel>methods</parallel>
                    <threadCount>10</threadCount>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
                <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <server>tomcat</server>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.6</source>
                    <target>1.6</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.4</version>
                <configuration>
                    <webXml>${basedir}/war/WEB-INF/web.xml</webXml>
                    <warSourceDirectory>${basedir}/war</warSourceDirectory>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.liquibase</groupId>
                <artifactId>liquibase-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.0.3</version>
                <configuration>
                    <propertyFile>liquibase/liquibase.properties</propertyFile>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id></id>
                        <phase>verify</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>update</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>

        </plugins>
    </build>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat-coyote</artifactId>
            <version>7.0.5</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat-api</artifactId>
            <version>7.0.5</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat-servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>7.0.5</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat-juli</artifactId>
            <version>7.0.5</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat-util</artifactId>
            <version>7.0.5</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat-catalina</artifactId>
            <version>7.0.5</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-c3p0</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.6.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate.common</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-commons-annotations</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.1.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.6.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.6.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-envers</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.6.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.0-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.1.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.0.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
            <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
            <version>4.2.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>joda-time</groupId>
            <artifactId>joda-time</artifactId>
            <version>2.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.17</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.mchange</groupId>
            <artifactId>mchange-commons-java</artifactId>
            <version>0.2.3.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.22</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.2.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-aspects</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.2.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.2.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.2.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.2.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.2.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-expression</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.2.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-instrument</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.2.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-instrument-tomcat</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.2.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.2.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-jms</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.2.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.2.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-oxm</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.2.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.1.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.2.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.2.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.2.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-simple</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
            <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.0.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>aopalliance</groupId>
            <artifactId>aopalliance</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>antlr</groupId>
            <artifactId>antlr</artifactId>
            <version>2.7.7</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>c3p0</groupId>
            <artifactId>c3p0</artifactId>
            <version>0.9.1.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>cglib</groupId>
            <artifactId>cglib-nodep</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-beanutils</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-beanutils</artifactId>
            <version>1.8.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-collections</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-collections</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
            <version>3.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-logging-adapters</artifactId>
            <version>1.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-logging-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.1</version>
        </dependency>
         //Jackson dependencies
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
            <version>1.9.12</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-core-asl</artifactId>
            <version>1.9.12</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.2.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-acl</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.2.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-aspects</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.2.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.2.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-core</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.2.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.integration</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-integration-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.3.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.integration</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-integration-mail</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.3.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
            <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.7</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-taglibs</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.4.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.liquibase</groupId>
            <artifactId>liquibase-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.3</version>
        </dependency>   
        <dependency>    
            <groupId>turbine</groupId>  
            <artifactId>turbine</artifactId>    
            <version>2.1</version>  
        </dependency>
        <dependency>    
            <groupId>net.sf.opencsv</groupId>   
            <artifactId>opencsv</artifactId>
            <version>2.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-fileupload</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-fileupload</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-dep</artifactId>
            <version>4.8.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
            <artifactId>mockito-core</artifactId>
            <version>1.9.5</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.github.springtestdbunit</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-test-dbunit</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.dbunit</groupId>
            <artifactId>dbunit</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.9</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
                    <groupId>junit</groupId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.jolbox</groupId>
            <artifactId>bonecp</artifactId>
            <version>0.8.0.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hsqldb</groupId>
            <artifactId>hsqldb</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.8</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hsqldb</groupId>
            <artifactId>sqltool</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- 
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
            <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
            <version>6.8</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        -->
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

Comment: Could you debug the server side? Is the request hiting your method body?

Comment: At you sending an "Accept" header with the request?

Comment: yes It is hitting the request body as i can see the print statements till the return statement @XtremeBiker

Comment: Yes I'm sending the Accept Header using rest Client plugin @JohnR

Comment: Have added kackson-core as well as jackson-mapper dependancies?

Comment: Serializing Entity object causing Mapping Exceptions that are not shown in log files,so serializing or returning view object rather entity object solved the issue. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spring MVC converts data to/from JSON (and other formats, e.g. XML) using **message converters** (implementations of the `HttpMessageConverter` interface).

The `<mvc:annotation-driven />` tag in your Spring configuration registers the JSON message converter (among other things that it is doing). The only other thing that you need to do to start using JSON in your web services is placing Jackson libraries on your classpath (you said that you have them already):

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Now, you also have some manual configuration for your JSON message converter:

```
<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter">
    <property name="messageConverters">
        <list>
            <ref bean="jsonMessageConverter"/>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="jsonMessageConverter" class="org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter">
</bean>
```

It is, probably, unnecessary. Try to remove it. The `<mvc:annotation-driven />` tag is all you need to register the JSON message converter.

Comment: Thanks, Yeah I removed it and you can check the added dependencies list in my new Edits. @Alexey

Comment: @SrikanthMalyala It's true for Spring 3.2 and 4.0. I do not know whether there are any differences in Spring 3.1.2 which you use.

Comment: Thanks Alexey, I created a dummy object in the request method and returning it instead of returning Donor object, it is working fine and I'm getting the response in JSON format,To test it I written code to manually convert the donor object to JSON format using ObjectMapper class then I come up with this exception "org.codehaus.jackson.map.JsonMappingException: could not initialize proxy - no Session (through reference chain: model.donor.Donor["deferrals"])"

Answer (score 1):

Http Status code 500 is for internal server error.If you are creating a rest web service why don't you return valid internet media type like JSON , XML or YAML. You can use jackson library to map your 'Donor' reference to json/xml and then return it from the server. At the client end you can again map the json/xml to Donor reference using jackson library.

Comment: Yeah Thanks, The last option is to convert manually the object using jackson API and return it as a string

Answer (score 1):

Try this way:

**Controller:**

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping(value = "/testshare/service/location", produces = "application/json", consumes = "application/json")
public class LocationController {

    @Autowired
    private IStaticContentService staticContentService;

    /**
     * Service method to retrieve all <b>Locations</b> detail.
     * 
     * @return response LocationResponse
     * @throws ApplicationException
     */

    @RequestMapping(value = "/getAllLocations", produces = "application/json", method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes = "application/json")
    @ResponseBody
    public LocationResponse loadAllLocations(@RequestBody BaseRequest request) {
        LocationResponse response;

        try {

            response = staticContentService.getAllLocation();
            response.header = ResponseBuilder.buildHeader(true);

        } catch (ApplicationException e) {
            response = ResponseBuilder.buildError(e, new LocationResponse());
        } catch (RuntimeApplicationException e) {
            response = ResponseBuilder.buildResponse(e, new LocationResponse());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            response = ResponseBuilder.buildResponse(e, new LocationResponse());
        }

        return response;
    }

}
```

**BaseRequest class:**

```
   import org.codehaus.jackson.annotate.JsonProperty;

public class BaseRequest {
    @JsonProperty("header")
    public Header header;
}
```

**In your spring configuration:**

```
 <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.ContentNegotiatingViewResolver">
        <property name="order" value="1" />
        <property name="mediaTypes">
            <map>
                <entry key="json" value="application/json" />
                <entry key="file" value="multipart/form-data" />
            </map>
        </property>

        <property name="defaultViews">
            <list>
                <!-- JSON View -->
                <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.json.MappingJacksonJsonView" />
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>
```

Maven dependency for Jackson 
    
            org.codehaus.jackson
            jackson-mapper-asl
            1.9.3

I have this checked with spring version 3.2.2.RELEASE.Should work for higher spring version as well

Comment: Oh Okay here I'm using spring version 3.1.2.RELEASE.

Comment: Serializing Entity object causing Mapping Exceptions that are not shown in log files,so serializing or returning view object rather entity object solved the issue. Thanks