# REST controller returns a plain String instead of JSON

Tags: spring

My goal is to bootstrap Spring and call a `Controller` and receive a `JSON` object as a response.

My problem is that after I implemented everything, I am only getting a plain string in the response body, but no real `JSON`. What did I do wrong?

I read something about `Jackson` - maybe is that the key to my problem?

Comment: Please show us the code you are trying to use

Comment: Have a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24774510/2842067).

Answer (score 1):

**1)** Make sure, you have Jackson in your dependencies.
In case you are using maven, enter this in your `pom.xml`.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-core-asl</artifactId>
    <version>1.9.13</version>
</dependency>
```

Taken from [MVN-Repository](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.codehaus.jackson/jackson-core-asl/1.9.13)

**2)** If you have Jackson in your dependencies, Spring will use it automatically.
Make sure, you return an `Object` e.g. `Person`, `Employee` and no `String`. Jackson will take care fo the rest

**3)** And do not forget to annotate your Method with `@ResponseBody`.

Comment: Note that this is an outdated version of Jackson.